# php preg_match_all find gettext language strings in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

**Hello**

So i am trying to find multi gettext language string in a string in php.

**Like so:**

```
$test = "
    sadsssss_('test1');

    sdfsd _('test2');
";
preg_match_all("/_('(.*?)')/s", $test, $matches);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

This example dont work, but then again i dont know much about patterns.

Tried googling it, was unable to find a pattern i could use.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to escape the parenthesis `_\('(.*?)'\)` or use a negated character class `_\('([^'\n]+)'\)`. Then your match will be in the first capturing group `print_r($matches[1]);`

Comment: Also you can use more difficult regex to match all types of quotes `_\([\'\"](.*)[\'\"]\)`

Comment: @VitaliyKrushelnitsky I think that will match more due to the `.*` and OP uses the `/s` flag where the dot matches a newline. https://regex101.com/r/uI542C/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original expression is just fine, we just might want to add a `m` flag:

```
\('(.+?)'\)
```

#### Test

```
$re = '/\(\'(.+?)\'\)/m';
$str = '    sadsssss_(\'test1\');

    sdfsd _(\'test2\');
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach ($matches as $key => $value) {
    echo $value[1] . "\n";
}
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/QCsJ6v/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]